# What is the accuracy of an artificial satellite at a certain magnitude?

Tags: astrophysics, artificial-satellite, mathematics

When we say that 'accuracy of gaia satellite is 10 $\mu$as at $V = 10$ magnitude in position and annual proper motion'. What does this mean? Does it change over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is the precision with which the astrometry (position) of stars will be measured with the [Gaia](http://sci.esa.int/gaia/) satellite.

The sentences you refer to in [Perryman et al. (2014)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0129)  are "Gaia will achieve accuracies of some 10μas (microarcsec) in positions and annual
proper motions for bright stars (V ∼ 10), degrading to around 25μas at V = 15, and to around 0.3 mas (300μas) at V = 20 (Lindegren et al. 2008)."

What this means is that after the 5-year Gaia mission is complete, the angular position (or coordinates) of 10th magnitude stars on the sky will be determined with a relative precision of 10 millionths of an arcsecond.  This will also be the accuracy with which the annual tangential motion (the so-called [proper motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_motion)) of stars can be measured. i.e. 10th magnitude stars will have an uncertainty in their proper motion of $\pm 10 \mu$as/year.

Comment: Could you give the author name (or a link) please.

Comment: http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/789/2/166/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I still didn't understand the sentence 'will be determined with a relative precision of 10  millionths of an arc second'. Lets say there are 2 stars A & B with equatorial coord. (a1, b1) and (a2, b2) then how does the above sentence fits in this context.

Comment: @raj ?  It means that $a_1$ is determined to somewhat better than 10 microarcseconds, as are $b_1$, $a_2$ and $b_2$. All with respect to a coordinate frame which I believe is based on distant quasars.